# Why is DoctrineExtensions Blameable eagerly fetching all created_by users

Tags: doctrine, symfony, doctrine-extensions

When using the following trait in my user class

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
protected $createdBy;

/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="update")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
protected $updatedBy;
```

Whenever i query a user the createdBy user is also fetched and this goes on recursively..

So if user C that was created by B, that was created by A is queried. All three users will be fetched...

Is there a way to disable always fetching the referenced user?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your ManyToOne declaration to use lazy loading:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", fetch="LAZY")
```

As mentioned in a similar question, when using lazy loading you avoid joining that data in the initial query and instead will only query for it when the property is accessed.
[What is the difference between fetch="EAGER" and fetch="LAZY" in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine)

Comment: Thnx for the tip but i have already tried LAZY and EXTRA_LAZY loading but it seems that some part of the blameable implementation still specifically requests the association.

Comment: How are you querying for the user?

Comment: $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('PidzUserBundle:User',1);

Comment: @JeroenvanSchelven any news regargind this problem? I have the same and I don't know how to overcome it.