# Fetch entity without related objects doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following classes:

```
class Category {

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
    */
    private $products;

    ...
}

class Product {

    ...

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $category;

    ...

}
```

when i try to fetch one product from my db like this:

```
    $query = $doctrineManager->createQuery(
        "
SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p
WHERE p.id = :id
        "
    )->setParameter('id', $id);

    $result = $query->getSingleResult();
```

i get not only my `product`, but also get `category` with all products (except the one i found). So, how can i fetch only model what i want without any related model?

Comment: why don't you use `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($id)`?

Comment: @DenisAlimov it doesn't matter. i get same result with what you post.

Comment: it called associations `DQL SELECT statements are a very powerful way of retrieving parts of your domain model that are not accessible via associations. Additionally they allow to retrieve entities and their associations in one single SQL select statement which can make a huge difference in performance in contrast to using several queries.`  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Comment: @DenisAlimov i know what it is. My question was `So, how can i fetch only model what i want without any related model?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are just stubs, you don't actually fetch any related entity information unless you are using fetch=EAGER.

This answer explains it pretty well.

[What is the difference between fetch="EAGER" and fetch="LAZY" in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine)

In summary, you can't get rid of the associations, but they don't load the other entities until you call the data unless you specifically request otherwise. So don't worry about it.