# Symfony3 One-To-Many relation not working

Tags: php, symfony, one-to-many

I have entity `Project` and `Files`. One project can have multiple files and one file belongs only to one project. Here is how my relationship is done

In `Files` Entity

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $project;
```

In `Project` Entity:

```
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Files", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $files;
```

Here is how a new File is created after being uploaded

```
public function createFile($fileName,$project,User $user){
        $file = new Files();
        $file->setFilePath($this->targetDirectory."/".$fileName);
        $file->setFromUser($user->getType());
        $file->setProject($project);
        $file->setDate(new \DateTime());
        dump($file);
        $this->entityManager->persist($file);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
```

This function is called in `ProjectController` after flushing the project (which gives it ID which then I can use to create my file). Here is the code

```
$projectService->createProject($project, $user, $isWithoutTerm, self::NO_TERM_DEFAULT_VALUE);
$filesService = $this->get('app.service.files_service');
foreach ($managerFiles as $managerFile) {
   $fileName = $filesService->uploadFileAndReturnName($managerFile,$this->getParameter('files_directory'));
   $filesService->createFile($fileName, $project, $user);

 }
```

After everything is set and done I have a project and files. In files table I see that `project_id` is with the id of the created project. Then I try to get from the project all files using `files` property. In my controller I have `dump(project->getFiles());` which so far returns this
[image]

Even though I have in my database files which have the id of the project my `files` is not filled with files. I suppose my mistake is in the annotations, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relations are (by default) loaded lazy in Doctrine. Meaning: it isn't fetched from the database until you access it.

Try to foreach through the getFiles. You will see you can access them.

[What is the difference between fetch="EAGER" and fetch="LAZY" in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine) including further links in that Top Answer to Doctrine itself to explain it further.