# Entity not Found Exception on Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, zend-framework2

**Scenario:** I have two entities. Product & ProductGroup. Product has many to one relation to ProductGroup. I soft delete the ProductGroup. Then I try to call getProductGroup on a product which has a product group which was soft deleted.

**Problem:** instead of expected null result I get an "Message: Entity was not found." exception message.

```
$productGroupName = $product->getProductGroup() !== null ? $product->getProductGroup()->getName() : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of proxies Doctrine2 was generating, not the case with `soft-deletable` though I'm using that. But in entities where this `soft-deleteable` wasn't implemented i was having the same issue. so what fixed for me is Adding `fetch="EAGER"` on Entities Annotations where relation was defined. like

```
/**
 * @var \ReisesparerAPIs\Entity\Vouchers
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ReisesparerAPIs\Entity\Vouchers", inversedBy="couponOrder", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="voucher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $voucher;
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine)