# How can I get access to ArrayCollection data inside my Array (Symfony 4)?

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

`fields table`:

[image]

`productgroup table`:

[image]

In my Controller I load my `fields_array` like this:

```
$fields_array = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(class::fields)->findAll();
```

If fields and productgroup are not connected my `fields_array` looks like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7460 ▼
    -id: 3
    -name: "cat"
    -unique_id: "5a38c820ed"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7464 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: Fields {#7460}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#2815 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "fields"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#6494 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#7465 ▼
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
    }
    -type: Type {#7541 ▶}
  }
  1 => Fields {#7542 ▼
    -id: 4
    -name: "horse"
    -unique_id: "bd7762b0e6"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7543 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: Fields {#7542}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#2815 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "fields"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#6494 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#7544 ▼ 
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
    }
    -type: Type {#7545 ▶}
  }
]
```

As you see the `ArrayCollecton` does not contain any elements.

So now I connect `cat` with the productgroup `Animals`. So my table `fields_productgroup` looks like this:

[image]

Now as you see, my `ArrayCollection` of `cat` contains the element `Animals`:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7460 ▼
    -id: 3
    -name: "cat"
    -unique_id: "5a38c820ed"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7464 ▼
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -owner: Fields {#7460}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#2815 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "fields"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#6494 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#7465 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
          0 => Productgroup {#7146 ▼
            -id: 6
            -name: "Animals"
            -unique_id: "9e4ef1c46f"
            -fields: PersistentCollection {#7357 ▶}
          }
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
    -type: Type {#7541 ▶}
  }
  1 => Fields {#7542 ▼
    -id: 4
    -name: "horse"
    -unique_id: "bd7762b0e6"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7543 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: Fields {#7542}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#2815 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "fields"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#6494 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#7544 ▼
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
    }
    -type: Type {#7545 ▶}
  }
]
```

Now I connect `horse` also with the productgroup `Animals`. So my table `fields_productgroup` looks like this:

[image]

My `fields_array` for `horse` shows, that there is an element in the `ArrayCollection` but it does not contain the information for `Animals`. It is just an empty array... But I actually need the information to which productgroup horse is connected

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Fields {#7460 ▼
    -id: 3
    -name: "cat"
    -unique_id: "5a38c820ed"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7464 ▼
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -owner: Fields {#7460}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#2815 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "fields"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#6494 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#7465 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
          0 => Productgroup {#7146 ▼
            -id: 6
            -name: "Animals"
            -unique_id: "9e4ef1c46f"
            -fields: PersistentCollection {#7357 ▶}
          }
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
    -type: Type {#7541 ▶}
  }
  1 => Fields {#7542 ▼
    -id: 4
    -name: "horse"
    -unique_id: "bd7762b0e6"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#7543 ▼
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -owner: Fields {#7542}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#2815 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "fields"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#6494 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#7544 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
          0 => Productgroup {#7146}
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
    -type: Type {#7545 ▶}
  }
]
```

My fields entity:

```
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Productgroup", inversedBy="fields")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productgroup", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $productgroup;


public function getProductgroup()
  {
    return $this->productgroup;
  }

  public function setProductgroup($productgroup): self
  {
    $this->productgroup = $productgroup;

    return $this;
  }

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->productgroup = new ArrayCollection();
  }
```

Comment: You forgot to add how you get the data and how you mapped entities associations (the most important info) but I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between fetch="EAGER" and fetch="LAZY" in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine)

Comment: @gp_sflover I added the enitity data to my question. I tested your suggestion about fetch EAGER  `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Productgroup", inversedBy="fields", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")` but do not get a different result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you are confusing the PHP Objects with PHP Arrays. But judging from your screenshots it seems that you have exactly what you wanted, the "horse" object has its `productgroup` association fully loaded.

This can be observed in your dumps:

[image: Cat dump -- Related Productgroup uid is #7146]
[image: Horse dump -- Related Productgroup uid is also #7146]

As one can see the related Productgroup object's uid is #7146 for both the cat and the horse object, as expected since they are related the same product group.

I think that you just have been misled by the fact that horse's Productgroup is not expandable in your dump.

Comment: So this means, it is actually there? Just not extandable?

Comment: Exactly. I guess you didn't try to use it in practice, just dumped it.