# Doctrine 2 reverse MEMBER OF DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I've got **Profile** class with ManyToMany relation "links" and **Link** class.
I need to build DQL query to get all links for a some Profile **without** reverse relation (link->profile).

First idea was to simple use "MEMBER OF" but looks like it is not possible without direct relation.

MEMEBER OF is building subquery sql. Maybe there is a way to do something similar?

I can`t just use

```
SELECT l FROM Profile p LEFT JOIN p.links l WHERE p.user = :user
```

but i can do:

```
SELECT e FROM Link WHERE e.id IN (SELECT l FROM Profile p LEFT JOIN p.links l WHERE p.user = :user)
```

so i have this SQL generated:

```
SELECT ... FROM Link t0_ 
   WHERE t0_.id IN (
      SELECT t1_.id FROM Profile a2_ 
      LEFT JOIN profile_link p3_ ON a2_.user_id = p3_.profile_user_id 
      LEFT JOIN Link t1_ ON t1_.id = p3_.link_id 
      WHERE a2_.user_id = ?
   )
```

is there any way to build subquery directly to table profile_link without profile join?

Something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM Link t0_ 
   WHERE t0_.id IN (
      SELECT l.link_id FROM profile_link l 
      WHERE l.profile_id = :user
   )
```

P.S. there is no need to use Profile table.

```
profile_link.profile_id = profile.user_id = user.id = :user
```

i need a DQL query builder to build more complex query with filter/sorter/grouper support. I cant use native query here or modify Entity class. Maybe some kind of custom DQL function can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up.

ManyToMany realtion is simple pair of OneToMany realtions, so i created class to represent it.

```
class ProfileLink{

    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Profile")
     */
    protected $profile;


    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Link")
     */
    protected $link;
}
```

Now i can use DQL without reverse part on **Link** class

```
SELECT p FROM ProfileLink LEFT JOIN p.link WHERE p.profile = :user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are overthinking it.

You can get the links of a **Profile entity through the links relationship** defined.

I assume your Profile class looks like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link")
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="profile_link",
      *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")},
      *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="link_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
      *      )
      **/
     protected $links;

     public function getLinks()
     {
         return $this->links;
     }
```

You can achieve what you want by:

- loading the Profile entity
- getting the **links** relationship
- traversing through the collection returned which depending on the [relation fetch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine) (eager, lazy or extra lazy) will cause the entities to be fetched if not yet fetched from the above step.

In your controller, just do:

```
$profile = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Profile')->find(1);
$links = $profile->getLinks();
foreach($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getId();
}
```

This way 2 queries will be executed:

1) To fetch the Profile row, eg:

```
SELECT t0.user_id AS user_id_1 FROM profile t0 WHERE t0.user_id = ?
```

2) To fetch the related links, eg:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1 FROM link t0 INNER JOIN profile_link ON t0.id = profile_link.link_id WHERE profile_link.profile_user_id = ?
```

In the last query, **only the mapping table is joined**, not the Profiles table. The rows returned do not contain the profile data.

Comment: Thanks for reply, you are right. This are right SQL queries, but i need grouping/sorting/pagination support available only with DQL query builder. So i`m looking for DQL solution.