# entity relationship doesn't return expected results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Studyng symfony.. I have two entities like this

Articoli entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticoliRepository")
 */
class Articoli
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nome;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Categorie", inversedBy="articoli")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $categoria;
```

Categorie.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategorieRepository")
 */
 class Categorie
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $categoria;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Articoli", mappedBy="categoria", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $articoli;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nome;
```

On indexController i have

```
        $articolo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Articoli::class)->find(201);
```

why $articolo categoria.categoria and categoria.articoli are null?? It should be the name of categoria

```
App\Entity\Articoli {#755 ▼
  -id: 201
  -nome: "Articolo #1"
  -categoria: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Categorie {#742 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 29
    -categoria: null
    -articoli: null
     …2
  }
}
```

Inspecting the profiler the executed query is

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.nome AS nome_2, t0.categoria_id AS categoria_id_3 FROM articoli t0 WHERE t0.id = 201;
```

Should it be a join no?

thanks

Comment: if you dump `$articolo->categoria();` what is the result? ;)

Comment: anyway google "doctrine lazy vs eager loading" should help you, or read [What is the difference between fetch=“EAGER” and fetch=“LAZY” in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891658/what-is-the-difference-between-fetch-eager-and-fetch-lazy-in-doctrine)

Comment: fetch="EAGER"  oh yeah!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can join them or use EAGER-Property in annotation. 
Otherwise if you try to get the categoria, a second query will be executed with the categoria:

```
$articolo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Articoli::class)->find(201);
$categoria = $articolo->getCategoria();
```