# Entity relation OneToMany get onlye one record.. but many expected

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have some problems with 2 tables relation with Symfony

NucleiStastiche1M contain time-series data of Nuclei..

One Nuclei can have many rows oof NucleiStatistiche1M

**Nuclei SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE public.nuclei
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nome character varying,
    cognome character varying
)
```

**NucleiStatistiche1M** SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.nucleistatistiche1m
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    dataora timestamp NOT NULL,
    value1 character varying
    value2 character varying
)
```

I defined the relationship on Symfony so

**Nuclei.php**

```
/**
 * @var NucleiStatistiche1M
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NucleiStatistiche1M", mappedBy="nucleo")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $statistiche1M;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->statistiche1M = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Collection|NucleiStatistiche1M[]
 */
public function getStatistiche1M(): Collection
{
    return $this->statistiche1M;
}
```

**NucleStatistiche1M.php**

```
/**
* @var Nuclei
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nuclei", inversedBy="statistiche1M")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
*
*/
private $nucleo;
```

When i join the 2 tables i only get 1 record.. I do something like

```
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('n, t, u, ns, ns1m, ts')
        ->from('App\Entity\Nuclei','n')
        ->leftJoin('n.statistiche1M', 'ns1m');
```

I expect many record i don't undestand where is the problem, the only problema i think is
the joined table have same value on ID

thanks

Comment: What are you doing with $qb? We are missing too much of your code to get a clear idea. But I'm pretty sure the problem here is your mindset. I think your thinking in terms of table rows while retrieving objects. It's a different paradigm.

Comment: Nothing particular, getResults from query and pass them to the view. Let me know what details i edit answer

Comment: I expect to have a collection of objects into $nucleo->statistiche1M :/

Comment: I will update the answer with more code details and table data thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving objects, not table rows. This misunderstanding is very common when moving from plain SQL to an ORM.

To get the different related objects (in this case `Statistiche1M`) you would normally use a getter.

```
$nuclei->getStatistiche1M()
```

Which should return a collection of `Statistiche1M` objects.

In Twig you could iterate through the related object with a for loop for example.

```
{% for statistiche1M in nuclei.statistiche1M %}
 {{ statistiche1M.propertyToDisplay }}
{% endfor %}
```

One reason why you would use an explicit join in your query is to prefetch the related objects in a single query regardless of the fetch mode set on the entity.

When using LAZY fetching, a call to `$nuclei->getStatistiche1M()` would trigger another query to the database which could affect performance.

This answer explains very well the difference between the different fetch modes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895601

Comment: I made this exactly, i only get one record instead of many.. I have a getter method and use it into a loop to fetch data

Comment: Maybe update your question with code showing how you are using the objects and where the problem really is. I could have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Ok, understand the problem.. :( The joined table should have UNIQUE ids value, in my case the column "id" assume the same value repeated. 

I created a new column something like "ALTER TABLE test1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;" .. updated the entity.. and now the join return many records